# How to capture a screenshot using VBScript in TestComplete?

Tags: vbscript, screenshot, testcomplete

I'm using TestComplete. I need to capture a screenshot and place it in a particular folder. How to do this using VBScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture a desktop screenshot, use the [`Sys.Desktop.Picture`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/31232/) method. To save the resulting image to a file, use its [`SaveToFile`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/31697/) method:

```
Sys.Desktop.Picture.SaveToFile "E:\screenshot.png"
```

Alternatively, you can turn on the [Test Visualizer](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/28968/) to automatically capture screenshots for your test actions.

Comment: @YallaRamakrishna: If it worked for you, please mark it as solution answer so other people will know.

Comment: Actually i am new user for stack overflow.I really don't know how it will be marked please tell me the procedure.

Comment: @YallaRamakrishna: To mark an answer ac accepted, click on the check mark to the left of the answer: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Comment: What is "Sys" ? This doesn't worked for me, vbs seems to doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function CaptureScreenShot(ScreenshotPath )  
  'Generate Name of the Image 
  strimgFileName="Img\Img" & Day(Date)& Month(Date) & Year(Date) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now) &".jpg"  
  strImgFile= ScreenshotPath & strimgFileName   
  'Capture failure Screen shot 
  Set objPic = Sys.Desktop.Picture()  
  'Save captured Screen shot 
  ExecutionStatus = objPic.SaveToFile(strImgFile)  
  'Return Captured image name
  CaptureScreenShot=".\" & strimgFileName  
End Function
```