# Initiate "Sys" object in vbs

Tags: object, vbscript, initialization

i'm trying to do some stuff in vbscript, and i have to take a screenshot of the screen. I don't want to use an external executable ([Auto Screenshot using VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549077/auto-screenshot-using-vbs)).
I find a vbs which can be nice ([how to take screenshot by vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534547/how-to-take-screenshot-by-vbscript)) but when i use this, it use an object (Sys), but i don't know how to create it.

I find some resources [here](http://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/test-objects/controls/desktop/general/sys/index.html), but i really don't know how to initiate the object "Sys", apparently it's like already "in" the vbscript, but it doesn't works for me.

I tried some stuff (Set Sys = CreateObject("System") or things like that, but nothing works :(

I hope you'll find something ^^

Comment: It's not in VBScript and VBScript can't take screenshots.

Comment: @ACatInLove : so i can't do anything ?

Comment: And my question is how can i initialize "Sys" ?

Comment: Find the library `sys`,  it's not part of Windows.

Comment: @ACatInLove Soooooo what can i do ? Oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you've referenced looks like a low-quality question. The references to "Sys" that you see appear to be in a product called TestComplete. See [How to capture a screenshot using VBScript in TestComplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217362/how-to-capture-a-screenshot-using-vbscript-in-testcomplete) You'd need to acquire and install TestComplete to use it, or find another program to capture screenshots instead.